# How do I search for and install the latest version of MinGW-w64

Tags: installation

I wish to install the latest version of MinGW-w64 and was told the best way is to install it via Ubuntu's apt-get command.

How do I search for and install the latest version of MinGW-w64? I need the 64-bit version. What commands must I issue?

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want the Ubuntu one (**stable**) you can do...

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
   ```

   - BTW: It states 'Development environment targetting 32- and 64-bit Windows' so there is probably only 1 install for both systems on Ubuntu.
   - I used http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ to search for mingw
2. If you want the **latest**(=**bleeding edge**) you need to install from source.

   > From the  [Website](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Downloading%20and%20installing%20MinGW-w64).
   >
   > - Source files: if you're reading this, you probably don't want these.
   > - **Automated builds: these are daily or weekly builds of different versions of the toolchain components, packaged together in one bundle. Here there are also Linux and Cygwin cross-complers.**
   >
   >   - Automated builds with the 1.0 version tag are GCC 4.5.
   >   - Automated builds without the 1.0 version in their name are GCC trunk.
   >   - Personal builds: these are builds made by users, and approved by the developers and maintained by active users. They usually provide more features than the autobuilds.

---

See the answer by woto in [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) on how to add directories to PATH.

- Download the one you want from the [Automated Builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/). To install a downloaded toolchain package, just `untar` it to a directory of your choice and add the toolchain executables to PATH.

Comment: @ Rinzwind: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I am using Ubuntu 12.10. How do I add the toolchain executables to PATH? I am new to Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: @n00b edited it in :)